# Display Number of Facebook Likes as Text

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to create a widget like the Facebook widget found on [this site](http://gideonshalwick.com/). I'm not sure how they've done it but somehow they're pulling in the number of Facebook likes from their page via the API. I've found a few examples online but none seemed to work. Is it possible someone could point me in the direction of how I can display the number of Facebook likes (for a page) as text?

Please note that the site I need it for is Wordpress so either an existing plugin or just PHP code will work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it in php:

```
$fb_handle = "GideonShalwickUpdates";
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fb_handle."?fields=likes";
$get_data  = file_get_contents($graph_url);
$get_json  = json_decode($get_data);

$likes = $get_json->likes;

echo $likes;
```